# socket: Address family not supported by protocol error on raspberry pi with xenomai

Tags: linux, sockets, raspberry-pi, real-time, xenomai

I have been trying to run the `xddp-label.c` example as given in the [xenomai documentation](https://xenomai.org/documentation/xenomai-3/html/xeno3prm/xddp-label_8c-example.html) on my raspberry pi with xenomai patched kernel. I can compile the program just fine, but when I try to run it I get the error: `socket: Address family not supported by protocol`. I noticed I get the same error when trying to compile other xddp examples from the documentation. I suspect it has something to do with the `AF_RTIPC` macro and the sockets, but I do not know anything about socket programming, so I am not sure. I hope someone can help me with this.

I am using a prebuilt xenomai kernel on my raspberry pi from [this tutorial](http://www.simplerobot.net/2018/06/build-realtime-xenomai-3-kernel-for_3.html). I have tried running the program with a custom patched xenomai kernel as well, but without success.

For reference, the output of `uname -a`:

```sh
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.80-v7-xeno3+ #2 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 10 15:04:48 KST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

The makefile I am using to compile the program:

```sh
SKIN=posix
MAIN_SRC=xddp_label
TARGET=xddp_label
CC=g++

LM=-lm

CFLAGS := -g $(shell xeno-config --posix --skin=$(SKIN) --cflags)
LDFLAGS := -g $(LM) $(shell xeno-config --posix --skin=$(SKIN) --ldflags)
#CC := $(shell xeno-config --cc)

$(TARGET): $(MAIN_SRC).c
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

I run the program with `sudo ./xddp_label.c`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution myself.

While building the kernel, in the kernel configuration the `CONFIG_XENO_DRIVERS_RTIPC_XDDP` option needs to be enabled.